# Authenticate using Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are trying to implement Azure AD B2C for our .Net applications. I was able to integrate and authenticate my web application. That's not a problem. My web application when authenticated, allows login and when not authenticated, redirects to the auth page. Works well.
But I don't want the B2C to redirect for auth. I want my webapp to call my API and my API should make a B2C API call, send the id and password and get a True/False decision on authentication.
Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) flow.

Comment: I went through the ROPC. From what I understand, this flow is for authenticating and authorizing an API. In my case, yes, the API needs to authenticate itself but it should also send the end user credentials to get a authenticated/not-authenticated response.

Comment: For Example, My username is Feroz and password is Pwd1. My webapp makes a call to an API with the name "AuthController". This AuthController has an application id, username and password setup in B2C. Once the AuthController is authenticated, I need a decision from B2C whether the UserName: Feroz and Pwd: Pwd1 is authenticated or not.

Comment: for an api, we usually use an access token in the request header to indicate if the request is authorized. for authentication, we need to use username + password to going to the sign in page. When the user is authenticated, then he will get the valid id token. Hence, according to your description, it seems to mismatch any of the azure ad authentication flow.....